# What is the the best method to retrieve text data from an external file in android?

Tags: android, url, listview, text

I'm pretty new to java and somewhat new to android and I've been looking everywhere for the past 3 or 4 days but cant seem to find the answer to my question. I'm making an app that is pretty simple and has only one real main function and that is to pull movie names, release dates, and the movie's format (dvd, blu-ray etc) into the app automatically.

Now I have everything set up and in place and I'm able to input the information manually via a base-adapter and string file but would like to have the ability to upload the information onto my server space which will then give my app (and myself) the ability to update the information as well as place it into the 3 line listview format I've already established.

Now I've been reading about Simple:XML, gson, SAX, etc but seeing as the information is just 3 small lines of text my question is what would be the best route as to the format of the file (i.e. xml, json, plain text, etc) and how would I go about getting this information into my app on the fly? I've included some code snippets below in the hopes they will make my question a little more clear.

**The string class for each result**

```
public class SearchResults { 
private String Name = ""; 
private String Date = ""; 
private String Format = ""; 

public String getName() { 
return Name; 
} 
public void setName(String Name) { 
this.Name = Name; 
} 
public String getDate() { 
return Date; 
} 
public void setDate(String Date) { 
this.Date = Date; 
} 
public String getFormat() { 
return Format; 
} 
public void setFormat(String Format) { 
this.Format = Format; 
}
```

**This below is where the actual list-view is populated and shown. Each new search result creates a three line text-view.**

```
private ArrayList<SearchResults> GetSearchResults(){ 
ArrayList<SearchResults> results = new ArrayList<SearchResults>(); 

SearchResults sr1 = new SearchResults(); 
sr1.setName("Movie #1"); 
sr1.setDate("July 24th"); 
sr1.setFormat("DVD, Blu-Ray"); 
results.add(sr1); 

sr1 = new SearchResults(); 
sr1.setName("Movie #2"); 
sr1.seDate("July 19th"); 
sr1.setFormat("DVD, Blu-Ray, Digital"); 
results.add(sr1); 


return results; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing data like this you would want to use a [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db). However if you need to read from the file first I would use a BufferedReader, this [article](http://huuah.com/android-writing-and-reading-files/) shows its application.